# Fridge turning itself off, comes back on when I twist temperature to minimum

Tags: refrigerator

I live in a 3rd floor flat here in the UK. On a number of occasions I'll wake up to find the fridge still a little cool, but definitely not having been running for a while (milk is warmer than usual, condensation on surfaces in the fridge). This has happened about once a month, but is getting more frequent. The "fix" we have found, is to turn the temperature dial (usually set to "4" on a scale from 1 to 7 with 7 coldest) all the way to 7, then we hear the fridge start humming again, and we put the dial back to 4. It usually stays fine for a while after.

We don't own the place, but plan to be living here for a while. Any suggestions as to what's going on/things we might be able to do to extend the lifespan of the fridge?

Comment: Tell the landlord - presumably it's their fridge. If the thermostat's failing, simplest fix is a new thermostat. If it's anything more, cheapest fix is a new fridge.

Comment: Your defrost cycle might have shifted closer to the time you're getting up.